# Unable to open excel using ApachePOI - Getting Exception

Tags: java, apache-poi

While trying to open an excel using ApachePOI I get

`org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Can't open the specified file: 'C:\Users\mdwaipay\AppData\Local\Temp\poifiles\poi-ooxml-1570030023.tmp'`

I checked. No such folder is being created. I am using Apache POI version 3.6.

Any help? A similar code was running fine in a different workspace. At loss of thoughts here.

Code:

```
public Xls_Reader(String path) {
  this.path=path; 
  try { 
      fis = new FileInputStream(path); 
      workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis); 
      sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
      fis.close(); 
  }
  catch (Exception e) 
  { e.printStackTrace(); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: what is the excel version you are using.

Comment: Why are you not using the latest version of Apache POI? It has [lots of bug fixes!](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html)

Comment: Well thanks for the interest. @swamy: It worked well with another excel. Both .xlsx Any idea what can be the reason? :P

Comment: @Gagravarr: Updated the version too. :)

Comment: How are you opening the file? With a `File` object or an `InputStream` one? And if the latter, did you try with the former?

Comment: Don't post code in comments, it's not readable. Update your question with the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you taking a perfectly good file, wrapping it in an `InputStream`, then asking POI to have to buffer the whole lot for you so it can do random access? Life is much better if you just pass the File to POI directly, so it can skip about as needed!

If you want to work with both XSSF (.xlsx) and HSSF (.xls), change your code to be

```java
public Xls_Reader(String path)  { 
  this.path = path; 
  try { 
    File f = new File(path);
    workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(f); 
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 
}
```

If you only want XSSF support, and/or you need full control of when the resources get closed, instead do something like

```java
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(path);
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);

// use the workbook

// When you no longer needed it, immediately close and release the file resources
pkg.close();
```

Comment: Thanks man. I had this fixed after upgrading my POI and using a fresh excel.

Comment: Even with the new version, open from a File if you can, not an InputStream - it'll be quicker and use less memory