# error while reading an excel file in a network path

Tags: java, apache-poi

i am getting this error when i am trying to read an excel file in a shared path.

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Can't open the specified file: 'C:\Users\256923\AppData\Local\Temp\poifiles\poi-ooxml--706221975.tmp'

Comment: That may be because its not a valid `xls` file or its a `temp` file created by the system during an `autosave` or something! Are you able to open the file as such?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350775/unable-to-open-excel-using-apachepoi-getting-exception

Comment: @karan sharme: Please share the code where you are getting this exception. the provided information is not sufficient to understand it.

Comment: I think, Nambi has given exactly what you want... :)